# Как подставлять значения для вычисления в проинтегрированную функцию?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Как работать с функцией, проинтегрированной с помощью sympy? Как сделать так, чтобы в проинтегрированную функцию подставлялись значения для вычисления?

```
from sympy import
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
funk = input("Введите функцию = ")
init_printing(use_unicode=False, wrap_line=False)
x = Symbol('x')
integrfunk = integrate(funk, x)
print("Проинтегрированная ", integrfunk)
print(type(integrfunk))
A = []
for i in range(10):
    x = i
    znachenie = integrfunk
    A.append(znachenie)
print(A)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь методом [`.subs(x, <value>)`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) для подстановки значения и методом `.evalf()` для получения численного (вместо аналитического) результата.

Пример:

```
In [397]: funk = "x**2"

In [398]: integrfunk = integrate(funk, x)

In [399]: integrfunk
Out[399]:
 3
x
--
3

In [400]: res = integrfunk.subs(x, 10).evalf()

In [401]: res
Out[401]: 333.333333333333
```